# Lubuntu & modem-manager : crash on reboot

Tags: lubuntu, crash, reboot, modem-manager

I have Lubuntu on an ARM board (https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=227). All is going well, except one big problem with 4G...

By default, I can create a "Mobile broadband" connection but I can't connect on it. So i install "modem-manager" with "`sudo snap install modem-manager`" command.
I now can connect on my 4G and it works.

But the problem is that it crashes on every reboot (black screen). I did many Lubuntu fresh installs and some problem every time, when i install modem-manager with `sudo snap install modem-manager`, I could not reboot anymore after that (black screen).

PS : I use Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: Please clarify your release of Lubuntu, why you tagged *ubuntu-touch` which is a phone operating system that is different to Lubuntu you seem to concentrate on.

Comment: Oops sorry for "ubuntu-touch", it's a mistake. My release is "Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS". Thanks

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  Also an updated 16.04 system  reports as 16.04.7

Comment: Thanks. But it's the manufacturer who proposes the OS as it is already packaged for the board.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !!!
Add "blacklist qmi_wwan" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf file
Reboot
It works!